# SMTP email not working in ASP.NET7 + II7, but working in Telnet

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, smtp

Basically, we bought a new server with **Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5** and have set up an SMTP server. There are no special settings. The code used was working fine in **Windows Server 2003, IIS6**.

Here is a summary of the settings

1. port 25, all unassigned
2. Anonymous Access
3. 127.0.0.1 is granted to relay access
4. Anonymous Access set for outbound
   security.

I can send an email via **telnet 127.0.0.1 25**

The problem is I can't sent emails through a send a friend Asp.Net page.

For the ASP.NET SMTP Email in IIS7, here are my settings

1. Deliver email to SMTP Server:
   **127.0.0.1, port 25**
2. Authentication Settings: **Not Required**

In my web.config, I have the following:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp>
      <network host="127.0.0.1" port="25" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Here is the code-behind code:

```
MailMessage M = new MailMessage();
M.Subject = subject;
.To.Add(new MailAddress(e1, f1));
M.From = new MailAddress(sendemail, sendname);
M.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(sendemail, sendname);
M.IsBodyHtml = true;
M.Body = email_message;

SmtpClient sClient = new SmtpClient();
sClient.Send(M);
```

Here is the event log info:

Process information: 
    Process ID: 2840 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Exception information:

- Exception type: WebException
- Exception message: Unable to connect
  to the remote server

Request information:

- Request URL: ...
- Request path: ...
- User host address: ...
- User:
- Is authenticated: False
- Authentication Type:
- Thread account name: NT
  AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Any ideas on why I can send email through telnet but not an asp.net page?
Again, this send a friend aspx page was working fine in Windows Server 2003.

I also referenced this page, http://forums.iis.net/t/1157046.aspx and am wondering what I am missing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was running into that too some time ago:

This is what worked for me: (You have 2 IIS management consoles)

In **IIS6 Management Console (Yes IIS 6)** right click virtual server, Tab Access, Click Connection, Grant Access to 127.0.0.1, Click Relay, Grant Access to 127.0.0.1.

When it comes to IIS7, i really don't know much, i just solve the problem i run into to make my apps working. My server is professionally hosted so when it doesn't work usually one of the admins there gives me a solution or i fiddle around 'till it works.

Comment: Even for IIS7 you need the II6 managemet console to administer the SMTP service.